# How to access data in parentheses from Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm going to ask you how to access the data from alamofire.
Here is the source code to get the data using alamofire.

```
let alamo = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers:headers)

        alamo.responseJSON() {
            response in print("JSON=\(response.result.value!)")

            if let jsonObject = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
            {
                let ROW = jsonObject["rows"]!
                print(ROW)
            }
        }
```

And, in the console window of xcode, the following log is left.

```
JSON={
    metaData =     (
                {
            name = PID;
        }
    );
    rows =     (
                (
            000000009
        )
    );
}
(
        (
        000000009
    )
)
```

This request accesses my oracle data server and returns the select result.
The last four lines are the values ​​I get from accessing JsonObject ["row"].
I have to use this value, but I do not know how to use it.

It's only on the console.
I would like to convert it to a variable 'string' or 'int', but simply converting any type to 'string' or 'int' did not succeed.

Now only one row is selected, but there is a possibility that several rows may be generated.

example:

```
(
    (
        000000002
    ),
    (
        000000029
    ),
    (
        000000019
    )
)
```

I want to use it freely like an array.

example:

```
rows[0][0] = 00000002
rows[0][1] = 00000029
rows[0][2] = 00000019
```

Is there a way I can write this data, even if it is not necessarily this way?

Thank you.

Comment: `jsonObject["rows"]` gives you an array of arrays of string (`[[String]]`).

Comment: I knew that.
So I tried the following.
let ROW = jsonObject["rows"]!
ROW [0] [0]
Error content: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Search on that error. You will find many existing discussions.